# Codeception, WebDriver | How to hover, then click at a hovered location

Tags: webdriver, codeception

I am using WebDriver and Asserts as modules in my acceptance testing.

Using WebDriver, I am trying to click on a label that acts as the javascript anchor for a form checkbox (the actual checkbox being hidden and a ::before font element being used to represent the checkbox as checked or not).

There is a link in this label which is located at the center of the element; the position I assume is targeted by the click() method. Due to this, I can't just click() on the element, as it will click the link instead of triggering the checkbox.

I envisioned that the solution for this problem would be to moveMouseOver(), using coordinates arguments in order to displace it to the side, then to trigger a click... but click() does not allow for a click event at the current cursor location, instead requiring a selector to be applied, thus defeating my purpose.

Is there any way to accomplish what I am attempting in the current WebDriver module in Codeception? Alternately, is there a way to accomplish this targeting of an uneven element for clicking without the process I've outlined?

Thank you for whatever help you are able to give.

Comment: Can you share the html code or better link to the actual page?

Answer (score 1):

I use a workaround: just making element visible via JavaScript:

```
$I->executeJS("$('css_selector').css({'display':'block'});");
```